# How to get through Karthspire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm currently at level 11 and trying to get through the Karthspire Forsworn camp.
I don't have great loot and keep dying; do you guys have any tips on how to beat them?

Comment: You can wait with passing through Karthspire until you have gained some levels.

Answer (score 5):

### Skyrim will not prevent you from going to an area that is too high level for you.

[Skyrim's Level scaling](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling#Effects_of_Leveling) can put in you a dungeon that kills you very quickly, even in one hit. This means that you need to come back later. The most obvious example are the giants and mammoths that roam around. They WILL kill you in one hit in all but the lowest difficulty.

Luckily, the Forsworn camps are open and can be easily departed from. If you ever encounter a cave that has a name with anything to do with eyesight, make a manual save and prepare for the worst, because those caves have a one-way gate and you cannot easily leave, and they have some of the more difficult enemies in the game.

If you desperately want to get through that area, you can always change your difficulty to the lowest setting and steamroll over all the enemies.

Comment: +1: Level 11 is *far* too low for the Karthspire, especially with "not great" equipment. OP should go clear out some of the caves around Whiterun and come back when they're at least 15-20.